# Post to Stackoverflow

Tags: support, api, php

Is it possible to post a question to Stack Overflow using PHP in the same way that it's possible to post content to Facebook?

Answer (score 3):

As of this writing https://api.stackexchange.com does only allow the writing of Comments.

See https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write

> Starting with version 2.1, the Stack Exchange API provides limited support for writing to sites in the Stack Exchange network. There are a number of constraints imposed to prevent abuse and loss of quality on Stack Exchange sites.

And also http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/09/stack-exchange-api-v2-1/

> Oh, and our first set of write methods.
>
> It’s now possible to create, edit, and delete comments via the Stack Exchange API
>   We’re starting small, with the least important of our content, to safeguard the quality of our content.

Comment: *Technically* it supports more, since it's what the Android app alpha uses behind the scenes, but...shh, secrets.